# Having share socketio for all express route

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

App.js

```
 var io = socket_io();
 app.io = io;
 var socket = require('./config/socketio')(io);

 var routes = require('./app/routes/index');
```

socketio.js:

```
var config = require('./config');

module.exports = function(io){
    io.on('connection', function (socket, next) {
        socket.emit('hello', 'hello');
    });

    return io;
};
```

How can I use io from socketio.js without passing socket into each routes like this?:

```
var socket = require('./config/socketio')(io);

var routes = require('./app/routes/index')(socket);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use global variable. `global.io = require('socketio')`
another way is use `module.exports` but you need `require` every file